# Using ng-repeat to iterate through an object with song names as indices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object that I created using song names so I could dynamically add and keep track of occurrences of songs in a series of playlists.
Here is an example:

> {tracks: Object} 1,2,3 - Remix: Object  
>   trackAlbum: "Greatest Hits" 
>   trackCount: 1 
>   trackImage:https://i.scdn.co/image/26b654ecbe60b28397e6d8b5d829cebeeeb5590a" 
>   trackName: "1,2,3 - Remix"

What I would like to do, is in the html, use ng-repeat to order each song by the trackCount (highest to lowest), and have it display in a list.
Here is the current code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<form id = "playlistSearch" name="playlistForm">
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Spotify playlist search:</label>
  <input name = "search" ng-minlength = 3 placeholder = "Enter your    search.." ng-model = "playlist" class = "form-control" required></input>
  <p class = "help-block" ng-show = "playlistForm.search.$error.minlength">Enter 3+ characters</p>
</div>

<div class = "form-group">
  <button ng-disabled = "playlistForm.search.$invalid" class = "btn btn-primary" ng-click = "getPlaylists()" type = "submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
<div class = "container-fixed, results">
 <ol>
 <li ng-repeat = "track in allTracks | orderBy: 'trackCount'"> {{allTracks.trackName}} {{allTracks.trackAlbum}} {{allTracks.trackCount}}</li>                                                       
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html is not properly structured, you should close `li` tag and then use `track` instead of `allTracks` inside the `ng-repeat` div, that will provide you the access over the each element of `allTracks` object.

**Code**

```
<ol>
    <li ng-repeat = "track in allTracks | orderBy: 'trackCount'">
       {{track.trackName}} {{track.trackAlbum}} {{track.trackCount}}
    </li>                                                       
</ol>
```

Comment: Oh, my bad, I had to retype it into stackoverflow to get it to format correctly, it does have the closing tag in my code. Let me change that.

Comment: @Alex no it also has other mistake..look at update.. the replacement of `allTracks ` to `track` is important part..

Comment: Ah, got it, I see it. Let me try it! Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work. Could it be because the object is a global variable in my js file? I instantiate it as a global variable and then update the data within my controller. When I try to call the data, I have to specifically call the song name. I can't do allTracks[0], as that returns undefined. I have to call allTracks["some song name"] to get any data returned.

Comment: @Alex could you tell me, how your current JSON looks?

Comment: http://imgur.com/cpNYZAz
the names are song names, and then each one has sub properties that contain more information about the songs

Comment: @Alex is that `allTracks` data?

Comment: @Alex still I don't understand the problem..could you create a plunkr/fiddle please?